# How to deploy google firebase functions using cmd?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have a problem with a web hosting project. I created a new proyect in google firebase, and I executed the following commands:

C:\myproject>firebase init functions

C:\myproject>firebase deploy --only functions

But the site says this:

> Site Not Found
>   Why am I seeing this?
>
>   There are a few potential reasons:
> 1. You haven't deployed an app yet.
>
>    You may have deployed an empty directory.
>
>    This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it up yet.
>
> How can I deploy my first app?
>   Refer to our hosting documentation to get started.

What could I do for show, at least, some text when an user go to my project url?

Comment: follow this tutorial step by step or watch youtube video on this blog. you will understand everything.   http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-firebase-web-hosting-and-connect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you now invoke the Firebase CLI, it will only deploy the Cloud Functions in your project. It will not deploy the web site. In fact, the way you've run it, it probably didn't even create a web site to deploy.

Initialize the project with:

```
firebase init
```

And answer the questions this shows.

If you want to deploy the web site, use:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

More likely you should simply deploy everything to prevent running into this problem:

```
firebase deploy
```